# How do I make the items in a BoxLayout align from the top down?

Tags: java, jpanel, alignment, border-layout, boxlayout

I'm creating an application which has a BoxLayout in the CENTER position of a BorderLayout. I'm having trouble aligning the components inside the BoxLayout, as instead of aligning nicely from the top down, when one is added, they all realign so as to have equal spacing between each other. Here's my code(irrelevant code removed):

```
private void buildFrame() {
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    packageItemPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(packageItemPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    this.add(packageItemPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

(In the above code, "this" is the BorderLayout.)

After I added the items to the BoxLayout(packageItemPanel) I called packageItemPanel.repaint() and also called refreshFrame() on the main frame.

Here's a screenshot of what it currently looks like.

[image: screenshot]

I want the items to align from the top down without having equal spacing between them.

Help appreciated!

Comment: Try adding [glue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html#createVerticalGlue--) to the end of the container, then make sure to [add each new item at the index right before the glue component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add-java.awt.Component-int-).

Comment: I added `packageItemPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue())` and it.. kind of works..? The items still do the automatic alignment thing, but they don't go past the first two-thirds of the panel from the top down. I added the items using `panel.add(component, panel.getComponents().length-2);` Hope that somebody can help!

Comment: Remember that nesting layouts is common and recommended.  You can try putting your panel inside another JPanel, one which uses a GridBagLayout.  Add your BoxLayout panel to it with a GridBagConstraints that specifies a `weighty` of 1 and an `anchor` of GridBagConstraints.NORTH.  If you want the items to stretch horizontally, you can set `fill` to GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL.

Comment: That worked! How do I make the items also aligned next to the left border?

Comment: As described in [the BoxLayout documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html), you need to [set each item component’s alignmentX property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setAlignmentX-float-) to [Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#LEFT_ALIGNMENT).

Comment: I have tried that, it doesn't change anything for some reason. I'll mess around with it for a bit.